# Navigation Drawer with Wrong Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I implement a Navigation Drawer in My App, and i enable the Home button on my action bar, to open the Navigation. But the button must show a icon like a list. Like this:

[image: Home Button with right icon]

But on my application, show a back icon:

[image: My Application]

I compare the code (AndroidManifest, styles.xml, activity_layout.xml) and every seems look the same, but my application still displaying the wrong icon.

Someone can hel with this?

Comment: Can you post the code in your activity? Plus indications on the AppCompat library using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have this code somewhere in your Activity already:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You must also call:

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
```

to tell the activity to use the menu icon.

You must first add the menu icon .pngs to your drawables.  If you don't already have them, you can get them here: https://www.google.com/design/icons/

Comment: actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu); requires API>=18

Answer (score 0):

Put the drawables for the icon you need to display.
Then set the home icon for actio bar with code below:

```
action.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);
```